# Incorrect incrementation of the 'lvl' variable when parsing Markdown files to generate a table of contents in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, markdown

I'm in the process of creating a documentation hosting application, similar to gitbook, and to make it cross-functional, I'm using a SUMMARY.md file to create my file tree as follows :

SUMMARY.md :

```
# Table of contents

* [Introduction](./)

## Active Directory <a href="#ad" id="ad"></a>

* [Category X](path/to/category-x/README.md)
  * [Subcategory 1](path/to/category-x/subcategory-1.md)
  * [Subcategory 2](path/to/category-x/subcategory-2.md)
  * [Subcategory 3](path/to/category-x/subcategory-3.md)
  * [️ Tool A](path/to/category-x/tool-a.md)
  * [Subcategory 4](path/to/category-x/subcategory-4.md)
  * [Subcategory 5](path/to/category-x/subcategory-5.md)
  * [Subcategory 6](path/to/category-x/subcategory-6/README.md)
    * [Sub-subcategory 1](path/to/category-x/subcategory-6/sub-subcategory-1.md)
    * [Sub-subcategory 2](path/to/category-x/subcategory-6/sub-subcategory-2.md)
  * [Category Y](path/to/category-y/README.md)
    * [Subcategory 7](path/to/category-y/subcategory-7.md)
    * [Subcategory 8](path/to/category-y/subcategory-8.md)
    * [Subcategory 9](path/to/category-y/subcategory-9.md)
    * [️ Tool B](path/to/category-y/tool-b.md)
```

Basically, I need to have my sub-categories wrapped in a "cat title" class div to contain the category title and an icon which, when I click on it, will pull down the child articles and sub-categories with an event listener, like this.

```
<div class="cat-title">
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/README.md">Category X</a><div class="arrow">→</div></li>
</div>
<ul class="subcategory1">
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-1.md">Subcategory 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-2.md">Subcategory 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-3.md">Subcategory 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/tool-a.md">️ Tool A</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-4.md">Subcategory 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-5.md">Subcategory 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-6/README.md">Subcategory 6</a></li>
  <ul class="subcategory2">
    <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-6/sub-subcategory-1.md">Sub-subcategory 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/subcategory-6/sub-subcategory-2.md">Sub-subcategory 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-y/README.md">Category Y</a></li>
  <ul class="subcategory1">
    <li><a href="/path/to/category-y/subcategory-7.md">Subcategory 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="/path/to/category-y/subcategory-8.md">Subcategory 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="/path/to/category-y/subcategory-9.md">Subcategory 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="/path/to/category-y/tool-b.md">️ Tool B</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

To achieve this result I use this function :

```py
def summary():
    regex_link_name = re.compile(r'\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)')
    regex_title = re.compile(r'##\s+([^<]+)')

    with open('SUMMARY.md', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    html = ''
    lvl = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        line = lines[i]
        if not line.strip():
            i += 1
            continue
        if line.strip().startswith('*'):
            space_count = line.split('*')[0].count('  ')
            current_lvl = space_count
            if current_lvl > lvl:
                lvl += 1 #why tf is the first lvl 1 and not 0 when it's the last subcategory of a category, causes last subcategory1 to be a subcategory2
                #TODO : findout
                html += f'<ul class="subcategory{lvl}">\n'
            elif current_lvl < lvl:
                html += '</ul>\n'
                lvl -= 1

            matched = regex_link_name.findall(line)
            name = matched[0][0]
            link = matched[0][1]

            # Check if this line is followed by a sublist
            is_subcategory = False
            if i + 1 < len(lines):
                next_line = lines[i + 1]
                if next_line.strip().startswith('*') and next_line.split('*')[0].count('  ') > space_count:
                    is_subcategory = True

            if is_subcategory:
                html += f'<div class="cat-title">\n<li><a href="/{link}">{name}</a><div class="arrow">→</div></li>\n</div>\n'
            else:
                html += f'<li><a href="/{link}">{name}</a></li>\n'
            print(name, lvl)
        if line.strip().startswith('#'):
            html += '</ul>\n' * lvl
            lvl = 0

            titles = regex_title.findall(line)
            if titles:
                title = titles[0]
                html += f'<span>{title}</span>\n'
        i += 1

    with open('output.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
        out_file.write(html)
    return html
```

The problem is that, every time I wait for the last level 1 sub-category in a category, which is supposed to be of class subcategory1, the lvl variable is incremented once too often in my debugger.

I have absolutely no idea why this happens, given that I never manipulate the lvl variable.

It only happens when the subcategory is the last in a category, as in this case:

```
* [Category X](path/to/category-x/README.md)
  * [️ Tool A](path/to/tool-a.md)
  * [Category Y](path/to/category-y.md)
  * [Category Z](path/to/category-z.md)
  * [Category W](path/to/category-w.md)
  * [Category V](path/to/category-v.md)
  * [Category U](path/to/category-u/README.md)
    * [Subcategory 1](path/to/category-u/subcategory-1.md)
    * [Subcategory 2](path/to/category-u/subcategory-2.md)
  * [Category T](path/to/category-t/README.md)
    * [Subcategory 3](path/to/category-t/subcategory-3.md)
    * [Subcategory 4](path/to/category-t/subcategory-4.md)
    * [Subcategory 5](path/to/category-t/subcategory-5.md)
    * [️ Tool B](path/to/category-t/tool-b.md)

## Web services <a href="#web" id="web"></a>
```

As you can see, the subcategoryn tag has not even been created :

```
<div class="cat-title">
  <li><a href="/path/to/category-x/README.md">Category X</a><div class="arrow">→</div></li>
</div>
<li><a href="/path/to/category-x/tool-a.md">️ Tool A</a></li>
<li><a href="/path/to/category-x/category-y.md">Category Y</a></li>
<li><a href="/path/to/category-x/category-z.md">Category Z</a></li>
<li><a href="/path/to/category-x/category-w.md">Category W</a></li>
<li><a href="/path/to/category-x/category-v.md">Category V</a></li>
```

I tried a lot of things like looking around for a bad  closure, a 'lvl' variable bad incrementation but I found nothing